# Floor mat holder clip hook for 2003 Honda Civic

Tags: honda, civic, interior

I got Honda floor mats that fit the floor perfectly, and the driver's side has two holes through which hooks can hold it in place.  There are flaps with square holes for the clips to mount into, but the mats didn't come with the clips.

[image]

Where do I find them?  Everything I find says it's for another year of Civic.  Would something like [this](http://www.hondapartscheap.com/southbay/jsp/item_oem.jsp?catcgry1=CIVIC&n=83605-SDA-A02&d=HONDA_CIVIC_FLOOR_MAT_HOLDER) work, even though it says "2005-2007 Civic"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using some thick solid wire.  Strung it through the holes in the floor, and through the holes in the mat and twisted it to make it secure.

Answer (score 2):

Call around to local salvage yards or search eBay for 2003 parts.

Alternately, go by some used car lots with 2005-7 Civics and just compare them to what you have.